# How to return a row where joins ALL exist SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, ansi-sql

How do I return a row (preferably in ANSI SQL) when the joined table has ALL matching rows on my `on`?

Example of the wrong behaviour:

```
SELECT table1.*
    , whatever
FROM   table1
      INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.whateverrelation = table1.whateverrelation
                       AND table2.matching IN(1, 2);
```

will return every `table1` row with a matching relation on `table2` which is 1 OR 2 (i.e. will return a `table1` row with one or more `matching` fields.

How might I get something that returns only the `table1` rows which have `table2` rows related and whose `matching` are BOTH 1 and 2 (so an AND rather than an OR, so there would have to be at least one `table2` row with `matching` = 1 and at least one with `matching` = 2, so it would not show any `table1` row without both matches)?

I'd rather not do two joins to the same table, I'm aware I could just have a left join twice, one to match 1 and one to match 2, but I don't know beforehand how many matches I'll need.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You coud use:

```
SELECT table1.col1, ....
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
  ON table2.whateverrelation = table1.whateverrelation 
GROUP BY  table1.col1, ....
HAVING SUM(table2.matching = 1) > 0
   AND SUM(table2.matching = 2) > 0;
```

Comment: I adapted that to be: `HAVING SUM((table2.matching = 1)::int) > 0` as postgres had a problem summing booleans. It's still convoluted but might be the best I can get. If there's a way to combine those two then that would be perfect.

Comment: @DanDart Yes, `SUM(... > 0)` will work with MySQL (question tag). If you are using PostgreSQL then use `CASE` as you proposed.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get it to work SQL-agnostically.

Comment: Well either way, works for me. Will have to figure out how to make bool = int database agnostic, but that's a different question. Marking as accepted. Cheers